# How can I be sure that Management Studio Saves my Script in ANSI format?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

Is there a way to check/set SQL Management Studio so that it saves my scripts in ANSI format but not any other formats like utf8 or so?

Comment: You know that Unicode is safer for scripts?

Comment: You can be right; but it is a kind of request for some environment which I need to provide my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Save File As` dialog you can click on the down-arrow on the save button to save with the encoding of your choice.

Comment: So, Western European (Windows)  - CodePage 1252 is the ANSI one?